# october cms htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: octobercms

When I go to Table, I get an error about passing an array in the code. But I'm not.

I've tried commenting out the code where I pass the data. It still gives an error

php:

```
        <?php namespace Gosman\About\Models;

        use Model;

        /**
         * Model
         */
        class Table extends Model
        {
            use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
            
            /*
            * Disable timestamps by default.
            * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
            */
            public $timestamps = false;


            /**
             * @var string The database table used by the model.
             */
            public $table = 'gosman_about_table';

            /**
             * @var array Validation rules
             */
            public $rules = [
            ];

            public $jsonable = [
                'name'
            ];
        }
```